# What is the purpose of the Foo.js.Map file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and noticed that as well as the expected files I also see:

```
*.js.map
```

What is the purpose of these files, do I need to do anything with them?

Answer (score 2):

It is called a sourcemap and is required if you want to debug your typescript code in a modern browser or visual studio : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvD_ia7vkkA&hd=1